# GWT/ java- onChange event not firing 1st time through

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, event-handling, onchange

I have a validator on a widget dropdown textbox that when the value changes it needs to perform an action.

The problem is the first time the value of the dropdown changes, It passes over the change handler- onChange (event) in my validator. It does however catch it (and work) after the initial change (2nd change and after).

Not really sure if showing my code will help much because its a very simple validator, but I can if needed. I couldn't find much on my research with this happening for other people, but at the same time i feel like i have heard of others having this issue before. Is there a common reason this could be happening?

Inside my validate function of my mainWidget class is the following. It basically calls a mainValidate Class from there which i could post code to if needed.

```
for(int i=0;i<validatorsList.size();i++){
                try{
                    saveErrors .add(myValidInfo.getValidator(validatorsList.get(i)).validate(getText(), iElementID, getArchitecture(),(getDisplayRow()+1),this));
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    saveErrors .add("ERROR: Missing Validator "+validatorsList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using? Which widget are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to set a initial value?

Comment: yes I first had the initial value at null, then tried 1, made no difference... Using 2.2.0

Comment: so actually there is an onchange in the dropdown widget class that is fired every time correctly. can i listen to the onchange handler from a validator somehow?

Comment: Can you show the code how you trigger your validator?

Comment: Post your code so that some one can help you

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Updated in question